# Find and click a select which has no name, id or class?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Here is the `html`:

```
<select>
<option value="" disabled="disabled">Select segment</option> 
<option value="EQ">Equity</option>
<option value="NSE-FO">Futures &amp; Options</option> 
<option value="NSE-CDS">Currency</option>
<option value="MCX-COM">Commodity</option></select>
</select>
```

I have tried to use `xpath`, `select`, etc. But I can't seem to find a way to click this box and subsequently click the required option.

Things I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Segment']")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains='Segment']")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@label='Segment'")  #I can see why this wouldn't work
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use a parent or sibling...

Comment: @MosheSlavin yes, that might work. :) Thanks I will look into it.

Comment: Glad to help! if you need help you can just edit in some more HTML...

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Segment']")
```

should be

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Segment')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the select with the options, with this path:

`".//option[@value='NSE-FO']/ancestor::select"`

If you have more selects with this option, try to find a unique option for this select.

And if this select is inside other select, and the ancestor method returns more than one, I'm not sure if this scenario is possible, you can try with this other:

`".//option[@value='NSE-FO']/../../select"`